# $4n$ is a square modulo $d$ implies $n$ is a square modulo $d$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I was wondering if someone could help me on a small detail that I need to clarify. Let $d$ be a squarefree integer and $n$ be any integer. Then I want to show the following:

$4n$ is a square modulo $d$ $\Rightarrow$ $n$ is a square modulo $d$. Namely if $\exists x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 4n \mod d$, then $\exists x^{\prime}$ such that ${x^{\prime}}^2 \equiv n \mod d$.

This result would be straight forward if I could use Euler's Criterion by my module doesn't cover it and $d$ is not necessarily a prime.

I'm guessing that this result generalizes with any square instead of $4$.

Comment: If the condition is true for all prime $d$, then we can construct $x'$ with Chinese remainder theorem for squarefree and composite $d$s.

Comment: Yes sure, so just the primes to consider.

Comment: Then it follows easily because Legendre symbol is multiplicative, $1=\left(\frac{4n}{d}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{d}\right)\left(\frac{2}{d}\right)\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{d}\right)^2\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$ if $d$ is odd prime.

Comment: Yes, this is true but to show that Legrendre symbol is multiplicative one needs Euler's Criterion which we haven't shown in this module.

Comment: Can we assume that $d$ is odd ? Then, I have a complete solution. But I have no idea yet how to prove the claim for even $d$.

Comment: $d$ is a squarefree integer so it could be even.

Answer (score 2):

Proof for odd $d$ :

Suppose, $4n$ is a square modulo $d$, in other words $$x^2\equiv 4n\mod d$$ for some $x\in \mathbb Z_d$.

Since $d$ is odd, there exists an $y\in\mathbb Z_d$ with $2y\equiv 1\mod d$, and we have $$(xy)^2=x^2y^2\equiv 4y^2n\equiv n\mod d$$